# How to obtain new filename from old filename in the shell script?

Tags: bash, shell

I have an executable program that have input and output likes

```
./my_exe -i filename_input -o filename_output
```

I want to use the program to run all filename in my folder that has structure likes

```
root
|-folder_A
   |-abc.txt
|-folder_B
   |cdf.txt
```

So, we can use for to do it. But the problem is that I want to automatically make the filename_output from the filename_input by adding the extension '_processed' before '.txt' likes abc.txt is input file name
. Then the output will be abc_processed.txt

How to do it in shell script? This is my current for code

```
for sub_folder in "${root_folder[@]}"
        do            
            filename_input=$sub_folder/*.txt
            filename_output= filename_input/*.txt/processed.txt
            echo filename_output
        done
```

The output of my script is `root/folder_A/*processed.txt`. I do not know why abc is lost

Comment: The assignment `filename_output= filename_input/*.txt/processed.txt` gives `$filename_output` a literal `*`.  It does not do a glob expansion.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: Thanks. Do you have any solution for that?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want to do.  Do you want the space separated expansion of all filenames that match the glob to be the value of the variable?  That seems to be what you're trying to do, but does not seem to be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right solution depends on what you want to do with it.
You should loop over the files you want to rename, not the directories.

```
for f in */*/*txt; do
   echo "With path ${f} ==> ${f//.txt/processed.txt}"
   base_f=${f##*/}
   echo "Basenames: ${base_f} ==> ${base_f//.txt/processed.txt}"
done
```

You might want to use `find ... | xargs` for this when you want to call `my_exe` with these files.
Make sure your `*processed.txt` are not converted again!

Answer (score 1):

```
$ tree root
root
|-- directory-A
|   `-- abc.txt
`-- directory-B
    `-- def.txt

2 directories, 2 files
$ find root -type f -exec sh -c 'echo ${1%.txt}_processed.txt' _ {} \;
root/directory-B/def_processed.txt
root/directory-A/abc_processed.txt
```

or:

```
$ for dir in root/*; do ( cd $dir; for file in *.txt; 
    do echo "$file --> ${file%.txt}_processed.txt"; done ) done
abc.txt --> abc_processed.txt
def.txt --> def_processed.txt
```

Comment: Good but I want to use it in for because it will use the output for other task

Comment: Hi, I used it in my code and it does not work. I used ```filename_output= ${filename_input%.txt}_processed.txt```

Comment: I updated my question with the issue. Could you look at it?

Comment: @bigdataolddriver: it return `*processed.txt`

Comment: $(basename adc.txt|cut -d. -f1) i forget cut is needed to strip .txt